# Mac App Store apps without internet connection

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I want to set up a Mac running a recent version of OS X but I don't want it to be connected to the internet because of security reasons. Is it possible to copy and activate apps bought and installed from the App Store on an other computer to the one with no internet connection? I know that the App Store validates the license to install such apps and it actually needs an internet connection to do so. But maybe there is a kind of license key file that can also be coppied over to the air gapped box.

Answer (score 1):

YMMV. Every once in a while when the transferred app is opened for the first time, it will need to validate the Apple ID which the app was downloaded with, so most of the time it will work, but sometimes it won't.